# Simulink neural network data input

Tags: matlab, neural-network, simulink

I have a 2x147 matrix as an input and a 3x147 matrix as an output, and I trained the NN pattern recognition with the input matrix and output matrix. I then generated a Simulink model of the trained NN, and now I want to test the new dataset of same size (2x147).

I am getting the following errors:

> Error in port widths or dimensions. Output port 1 of `NN_Trail/Constant` is a [2x147] matrix.
>
> Error in port widths or dimensions. Input port 1 of `NN_Trail/Pattern Recognition Neural Network` is a one dimensional vector with 2 elements.

If I give a constant value of 2 elements, then the Simulink runs for the mentioned time and gives the desired output. How can I get it to work with the data I've described?

My idea in future is to connect the trained neural network to a simulated plant and find the abnormal data from the plant.

Comment: Is it a matrix signal, where  [ 2x147] gets changed at every timestep, or do you expect the model to run 147 steps and stop then?

Comment: Yes I want the simulation model to run 147 steps and then stop...

Comment: Does my answer below answer your question? If yes, you can accept it ..

Answer (score 0):

So your model has an input of dimenstion 2 and an output of dimenson 3. 
And you have an calculated signal of 147 timesteps that you want to run on the inputs.

To import that signal to your model you can use a Matlab time series object.

http://ch.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/importing-matlab-timeseries-data-to-a-root-level-input-port.html